# How to terminate a thread when the worker can't check the termination string

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have the following code running in a Windows form. The method it is calling takes about 40 seconds to complete, and I need to allow the user the ability to click an 'Abort' button to stop the thread running.

Normally I would have the Worker() method polling to see if the _terminationMessage was set to "Stop" but I can't do this here because the long running method, ThisMethodMightReturnSomethingAndICantChangeIt() is out of my control.

How do I implement this user feature please ?

Here is my thread code.

```
        private const string TerminationValue = "Stop";
        private volatile string _terminationMessage;


        private bool RunThread()
        {

            try 
            {
              var worker = new Thread(Worker);
              _terminationMessage = "carry on";
              _successful = false;

              worker.Start();
              worker.Join();

             finally
            {
              return _successful;
            }

        }

        private void Worker()
        {
            ThisMethodMightReturnSomethingAndICantChangeIt();
            _successful = true;
        }
```

Comment: How much out of your control? Do you have any idea what it does? Some I/O, or some complex computations? If you really have *no* way to get *it* to support cancellation, you're in trouble.

Comment: The Method being invoked is updating an Oracle DB behind a WCF service. I was trying to avoid Thread.Abort if possible.

Comment: Yup, Thread.Abort will not help at all in that case. However, both WCF and Oracle can be called asynchronously - that will allow you to issue aborts. Just have a look at the asynchronous WCF methods (you have to enable their code generation IIRC). Also, think about why do you need the abort. Do you just want to give control back to the user? You might be cool enough with just ignoring the background thread, or even just treating it as background - give callbacks rather than synchronously waiting for "done". Do you need to cancel that task? No way if the interface doesn't give you that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simple answer would be "you can't". There's no real thread abort that you can use to cancel any processing that's happenning.

`Thread.Abort` will allow you to abort a managed thread, running managed code at the moment, but it's really just a bad idea. It's very easy to end up in an inconsistent state just because you were just now running a singleton constructor or something. In the end, there's quite a big chance you're going to blow something up.

A bit orthogonal to the question, but why are you still using threading code like this? Writing multi-threaded code is really hard, so you want to use as many high-level features as you can. The complexity can easily be seen already in your small snippet of code - you're `Join`ing the newly created thread, which means that you're basically gaining no benefit whatsoever from starting the `Worker` method on a new thread - you start it, and then you just wait. It's just like calling `Worker` outright, except you'll save an unnecessary thread.

`try` will not catch exceptions that pop up in a separate thread. So any exception that gets thrown inside of `Worker` will simply kill your whole process. Not good.

The only way to implement reliable cancellation is through cooperative aborts. .NET has great constructs for this since 4.0, `CancellationToken`. It's easy to use, it's thread-safe (unlike your solution), and it can be propagated through all the method chain so that you can implement cancellation at depth. Sadly, if you simply *can't* modify the `ThisMethodMightReturnSomethingAndICantChangeIt` method, you're out of luck.

The only "supported" "cancellation" pattern that just works is `Process.Kill`. You'd have to launch the processing method in a wholy separate process, not just a separate thread. That can be killed, and it will not hurt your own process. Of course, it means you have to separate that call into a new process - that's usually quite tricky, and it's not a very good design (though it seems like you have little choice).

So if the method doesn't support some form of cancellation, just treat it like so. It can't be aborted, period. Any way that does abort it is a dirty hack.

Comment: I was joining the thread as soon it was created so that the UI winform thread was still responsive, and the spinning gif runs. It was also there to work towards the ability to respond to user's abort request.

Comment: There is error handling and Nlog use within the worker() but I omitted that to keep the snippet above clear

Comment: If Abort method is always a bad idea then it will ceased to exist's, If you know why/when/where to used Abort method it will be fine.

Comment: @SkeetJon Do start it on a new thread, that's fine. But instead of joining it, treat the response as a continuation - the end of the worker thread should actively signal the main thread and tell it "there's your response / error". `await` makes this incredibly easy, but you can also do with a manual continuation method that you'll `Invoke` from the worker thread.

Comment: @Jade Sadly, no. Microsoft gives a lot of weight to backwards compatibility, and this would be a big break. Instead, they're doing a lot of work to fix issues caused by `Thread.Abort` (for example, since 2.0, it can no longer abort inside of a `finally` clause - which also means another way to break the `Abort` from working :D). But it's still awful practice. MS created a lot of ways to handle aborts gracefully - use those.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my solution so far. I will definitely read up on newer .NET higher level features as you suggest. Thanks for the pointers in the right direction

```
    private void RunThread()
    {
        try
        {
            var worker = new Thread(Worker);

            SetFormEnabledStatus(false);
            _usuccessful = false;

            worker.Start();

            // give up if no response before timeout
            worker.Join(60000);      // TODO - Add timeout to config
            worker.Abort();
        }
        finally
        {
            SetFormEnabledStatus(true);
        }
    }

    private void Worker()
    {
        try
        {
            _successful= false;
            ThisMethodMightReturnSomethingAndICantChangeIt();
            _successful = true;
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
            // nlog.....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // nlog...
        }

    }
```

Comment: One more point - `Abort` doesn't wait for the thread to be aborted. Maybe that's okay with you, but if you're accessing shared resources, it may be that they haven't been released yet. You'd actually want to `Join` again after the `Abort` - and again with a timeout, except that this time, if the timeout hits, you know the abort pretty much failed and you're screwed :D

Comment: Oh, and also - is your `ThisMethodMightReturnSomethingAndICantChangeIt` method relying on some state it's modifying, or is it completely isolated (e.g. just taking parameters and returning a value)? If it is isolated, you could separate it into a new process or AppDomain (even that would give you more safety) relatively easily.

Comment: It is completely isolated so the new process idea sounds good in so much that it wont causes issues in the client application I'm modifying